# How to export function with hoc?

Tags: reactjs

```
 function UpdateID(index, id) {
    let CardsData = Cards

    var CardsObj = {
        link: Cards[index].link,
        icon: Cards[index].icon,
        name: Cards[index].name,
        png: Cards[index].png,
        id: id,
    }
    CardsData[index] = CardsObj

    setCards(CardsData)
    const [Cards, setCards] = props.value.Cards
}

export withUserData(UpdateID)
```

this is my code I want to export this const not `export default` 'cause I already have many other functions in one file I want to export them all.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: If you want it to be imported as `import { Example } from '/some/path'`, then do `export const Example = withUserData(UpdateID)`

Comment: please add it as an answer, so I can close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 function UpdateID(index, id) {
    ...
}

const userData = withUserData(UpdateID)
export { 
  userData 
}
```